# UIlabel text alignment in UITableViewCell not working

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3, uilabel

Sorry for the Chinese characters, but the UILabel text alignment displayed as right side NO MATTER which option (left, center and etc.) it is set. Please help.

```
// This is the function that populates the cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! WordLibraryTableViewCell

    let key = Int(dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
    let value = levelDict[key!]! as String
    cell.wordLibLabel.text = value
    return cell
}



// This is the cell class
class WordLibraryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var bookimageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var wordLibLabel: UILabel!


}
```

[image]

Comment: Add the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: are you using custom `tabelview cell`, show us your code

Comment: @NiravD, Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @AnuradhS, Edited, thanks!

Comment: did you try do delete the outlet connection to the label and reconnect it or align programmatically inside your `cellForRowAt` like `cell.wordLibLabel.textAlignment = .Left`

Comment: @AnuradhS, it turns out that there was an invalid imageView outlet connection with an exclamation mark, probably damaging the format of all outlets. And everything works fine after removing it. Therefore your suggestion was the way to check the error, thanks a lot!!

Comment: And also, Apple should definitely make this mistake more obvious!

Comment: you are welcome